# Program for making a complete ISO-image of damaged DVD by multiple readings?

Tags: iso, dvd, multimedia

I'm looking for a program that (tries to) makes a complete ISD-image of a damaged DVD or CD.  This is (AFAIK) done by reading the damged media time and time again, until the program is able to put together an undaged ISO-image of the whole disk.

I just can't remember what it was called or where I found it...

Comment: See my answer in that Q, I show how to use `dvdbackup`. I have 3 kids and they trash my DVDs, that's the only tool I've found + `ddrescue` that can salvage them.

Answer (score 1):

[`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/), beware there is another program called [`dd_rescue`](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/). The GNU version has a lot more to offer than this though. the webpage says it is superceded by the GNU version, but also give this:

> It's still useful though for some special features, such as direct IO, sparse copies, splice copies, preallocation ...
>   Noteworthy are the data protection functions that have been introduced since 1.29 to allow safe deletion of files and storage devices with a fast userspace pseudo random number generator.

Also consider a high-end drive if you can get use of one (local computer shop maybe?). This can make a big difference, I have had DVDs which I haven't been able to fully read at all (even with `ddresuce`) on a cheap drive which have read first time (no special tools required) on a different drive.